# Computer starts up to gray screen, in recoevery mode getting "Open Error 5: Input/Output error on System/CoreServcices/ManagedClient.app/*

Tags: startup

Computer starts up to gray screen, in recoevery mode getting "Open Error 5: Input/Output error on System/CoreServcices/ManagedClient.app/*

My computer turned to sludge, and I hit the power button and shut it down.

On startup, we got to login screen, put in my password, wait for minutes..no go

Manual shutdown.

On startup we get the white screen of death.

Put disk into recovery mode, got the recovery OS going, and opened disk utility.

My Macnitosh HD was still there, but I ran "Verify permissions" and got the above error for a long time. Eventually, I stopped the process and hit "Verify Disk".

This happened quickly, and it tells me that my Disk can't be repaired. (Not sure how to get a backup from the files I have, so help with that would be good)

When I go to the menu and hit "Statup Disk" my copy of Mountain Lion is not present.

Not exactly sure what to do in terms of backup, installing a new OS, repairs.

Whaty should I do?

Comment: Post photos of the gray screen you see. There are console log along the left side of display.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify what year/model your Mac is, and what operating system came with the system.

Let's assume that "Lion" came pre-installed and you have the option of a "Recovery Partition". You need to first format your hard-drive, removing everything (making sure that you have a back-up!!) and then:

1) Switch off your mac

2) Book your Mac and press and hold the ⌘ (Command) key and R key immediately; after the first chime sounds. You must keep holding down both the Command and R keys until you see a window with “OS X Utilities” across the top in large text. This *should* enable you to do a fresh re-install.

The second way to access the recovery partition is to re-boot your mac and hold onto the (options) key.

If you do not have a recovery partition on your hard-drive you need to seek someone who has a Mac with *lion*+ on and download the [OS X Recovery Disk Assistant v1.0](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1433) and placing a new image onto a memory stick, and following the steps above with the memory stick.

If your Disk cannot be repaired, then, there maybe an issue with the disk itself. Or, you could try and "Erase" the disk and doing a fresh re-install. Again, you need to TRY the best you can to ensure you back up all the data before trying any of these steps. But, it seems to me (personally) that this may not be an option for you.

I hope this helps :)